# What does @PrepareForTest in PowerMock really mean?

Tags: java, junit, powermock

What does the annotation `@PrepareForTest` in PowerMockito really mean?

What should be placed there apart of classes which have static methods?

Comment: Check docs here https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito

Comment: @GhostCat kinda, imo you need to pass the ClassUnderTesting.class there also if you want to mock private methods invokings of this class, also additionally you need to put Spy above the InjectMocks which is also above the ClassUnderTesting initialization.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That annotation tells PowerMock(ito) that the listed classes will need to be manipulated on the byte code level.

You need to "prepare for test" all these classes X of which you want to

- mock a [static](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) method (on X)
- gain control over calls to [`new()`](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) used in another class X
- gain control over private methods (which you do using a **spy** and
  `PowerMockito.when(spy, "privateMethodNameAsString").then...`

In other words:

- To mock `X.doStatic()`, you have to prepare the class X.
- To control `new Y(...)`, you have to prepare the class X that *contains* that `new` statement.

Comment: Just to add to that, it also lets you do things like mock an Enum.

Comment: Yes, but that is again something I dislike doing. If I need to "mock" such things, my enums implement some interface I can mock (without PowerMock).