# How to mock a parameter that being passed into a constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have a class as below

```
public Class CLZA {

     private Object obj1;
     private Object obj2;
     private StringBuilder strBuilder;

     public CLZA (CLZB objB) {
          obj1 = objB.fetchValueOfObj(Request.type1);
          obj2 = objB.fetchValueOfObj(Request.type2);
          strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     } 

     public double computeValue(...) {
          if (this.obj1 == 1.0) {
              ...
          }
          if (this.obj2 == 2.0) {
              ...
          }
          strBuilder.append("This is the line I got NPE now");
     }
}
```

Right now, I am trying to do something like this.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CLZA.class, StringBuilder.class})
public class ClzATest {

    private CLZA objA;

    @Mock
    private CLZB objB;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        objA = new CLZA(objB);
        when(objB.fetchValueOfObj(any(Request.class))).thenAnswer(
                invocation -> {
                    Object argument = invocation.getArguments()[0];
                    if (argument.equals(Request.type1)) {
                        return 1.0;
                    } else if (argument.equals(Request.type2)) {
                        return 2.0;
                    } else {
                        return 0.0;
                    }
                });

    }

    @Test
    public void testComputeValue() {
        double value = objA.computeValue(...);
        assertEquals(2.0, value);
    }
}
```

I have following questions/issues:

1. As you can see, I want to mock the value of the objB returned. Can I
   pass the mocked objB to the constructor when I instantiate the Class
   CLZA? should I mock CLZA also? If I need to mock CLZA, how can I
   related it to my mocked objB?
2. Right now, I keep getting NullPointerException at the line
   `strBuilder.append("This is the line I got NPE now");`. It seems strBuilder is not instantiated. Can anyone
   help on how to test in this scenario?

Appreciate it.

Comment: Move the line with `objA = ` to _after_ the line with `when`.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica, I moved `objA = new CLZA(objB);` after `when(objB.fetchValueOfObj(any(Request.class))).thenAnswer(...`, it still throw NPE.

Comment: There is nothing in your posted test that requires `@PrepareForTest({CLZA.class, StringBuilder.class})` I would guess that is messing with the `CLZA` constructor. See [what does preparefortest really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430071/what-does-preparefortest-in-powermock-really-mean)

Comment: @DCTID, I removed the `PrepareForTest...`, it still throw NPE. :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the NPE was caused by another issue. This unit testing is working fine. Sorry for the misleading.