# Mock a private void method using PowerMockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

```
public class Abcd {
    
    public String one() {
        System.out.println("Inside method one");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        two(sb);
        return "Done";
    }
    
    private void two(StringBuilder sb) {
        System.out.println("Inside method two");
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Abcd.class)
public class TestAbcd {
    
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
        Abcd abcd = PowerMockito.spy(new Abcd());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(abcd, "two", sb);
        abcd.one();
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Inside method one
Inside method two
```

No failure trace in edited part:
Failure trace:

[image]

Please let me know what mistake i am making, and how can i make it work.

Comment: Edited the question with new StringBuilder parameter for private function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need @PrepareForTest annotaion to gain such a control on private methods with PowerMockito.

See this article: [What does @PrepareForTest in PowerMock really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430071/what-does-preparefortest-in-powermock-really-mean)

In summary the test case should look like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Abcd.class)
public class TestAbcd {
    
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
        Abcd abcd = PowerMockito.spy(new Abcd());
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(abcd, method(Abcd.class, "two", StringBuilder.class))
                .withArguments(any(StringBuilder.class));               
        abcd.one();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thannkyou for providing that insight, i am stuck with another thing now, can you pls help me with it. Edited the question.

Comment: Updated the answer for the case when mocked private method has args