# Jacoco Code Coverage - Some classes not appearing in report

Tags: java, junit, powermock, jacoco

I am using maven jacoco pugin to generate code coverage report. I am using Powermock for my Junits. I am getting this message at the time of build:

**Classes in bundle "XYZ" do not match with execution data. For report generation, same class files must be used at runtime.

[WARNING] Execution data for class "com/abc/example/testEmail" does not match
...**

As per my analysis,wherever I have used @PrepareForTest on a particular class, that class is not showing up in the code coverage report.

I am using the following version of Jacoco and Powermock:

Jacoco - 0.7.9
PowerMock - 1.7.1

Comment: I think I understand the problem. jacoco takes each line of code and understand the what bytecode related to it. what PrepareForTest does is change the bytecode when you compile. so there is no match between your code and the bytecode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56430390/588532

Comment: Yes. How do I resolve this issue. Any indicators would be helpful.

Comment: I went through https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html  (What workarounds exist to deal with runtime-modified classes?) but any example fo the 3 workarounds would be helpful.